# Wiki syntax parser in Java

Tags: java, regex

I would like to make a wiki syntax parser in Java. I have one in PHP that goes a little something like this:

```
private static function runAllConversions($pString) {
    $tConverted = $pString;
    $tConverted = stripTags($tConverted); 

    // Bold and italic text.
    $tConverted = preg_replace('/\'\'\'\'\'([^\n\']+)\'\'\'\'\'/',
        '<strong><i>${1}</i></strong>', $tConverted);
```

In replacement I was thinking of replaceAll instead of the preg_replace in PHP. I guess it would be something like:

```
// Bold text in Java.
converted = converted.replaceAll('/\'\'\'([^\n\']+)\'\'\'/',
    '<strong>${1}</strong>', converted);
```

Any one got any good suggestions for that?
Thanks!

Comment: Why do you do so much backslash escaping when you could just use different quotes instead? `"/'''''([^\\n']+)'''''/"`

Comment: hmm. good point. Did not know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
converted = converted.replaceAll("'{5}([^\n']+)'{5}", "<strong><i>$1</i></strong>");
```

- I used `'{5}` instead of `'''''` but they are the same.
- The two delimiters `/` in PHP are specific to PHP. They should not appear in Java's regex.

BTW, you may use an [existing MediaWiki parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888063/parser-for-wikipedia) instead.

Comment: Thanks for that answer. Though I do not want to use an existing one. Maybe I should mention as well that I would like to convert the wiki syntax to html.

Comment: @Tim: Those existing ones can generate HTML.

Comment: Ok then. I will have a look at it. Thank you.